# Is there a way to "associate" one Xamarin Forms control with another?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a form with three "pairs" of {Entry, Button} defined in Xaml. Each button is intended to act on its corresponding Entry. Is there a way in the Xaml to "associate" each Entry with its Button? I am trying to avoid having to have three virtually identical methods

```
OnButtonAClicked()
{
    act on Entry A
}
OnButtonBClicked()
{
   act on Entry B
}
OnButtonCClicked()
{
    act on Entry C
}
```

I want instead one method

```
OnButtonClicked()
{
    act on my associated Entry
}
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bindings (haven't tested this, think it will work)

```
<Entry x:Name="EntryA" ... .>

<Button BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=EntryA}" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" ... />

<Entry x:Name="EntryB" ... .>

<Button BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=EntryB}" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" ... />
```

then

```
OnButtonCClicked(object sendrer, EventArgs args)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    Entry entry = (Entry)btn.BindingContext;

    // entry should be a reference to the appropriate entry
}
```

Comment: 's solution with BindingContext works like a champ! (Other than being missing an equal sign in Button btn = (Button)sender; <g>). Thanks!

Comment: Can't seem to get an at-sign reference into the above. The solution from @Jason

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Command` and `CommandParameter` instead of `Clicked` event, that way you can send the correspondent Entry control as a parameter:

```
        <Entry x:Name="entry1"/>
        <Entry x:Name="entry2"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry1}}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry2}}"/>
```

In your ViewModel or code-behind:

```
Constructor() {
   ClickCommand = new Command<Entry>(ClickAction);
}

void ClickAction(Entry entry)
{
    entry?.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cfun . Did not test; the solution below looked slightly more straightforward so I went with that.